# Why do I have so many apache2 processes?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I have a Debian 6.0.1 machine running GNU/kFreeBSD 8.1-1-amd64 and Apache. I installed `apache2-mpm-worker` using `apt-get`, and my `apache2.conf` file contains:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          4
    MinSpareServers       2
    MaxSpareServers       5
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          1
    MinSpareThreads       2
    MaxSpareThreads      20
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      20
    MaxClients          100
    MaxRequestsPerChild 400
</IfModule>
```

So I should see only a couple Apache processes running. However, it looks more like I am running prefork, because instead of many threads i appear to have many processes:

```
root@garrison:/# ps awwwwx | grep apache
78438 ?        S+     0:00 grep apache
78424 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78423 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78422 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78421 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78420 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78419 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78418 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78417 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78416 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78415 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78414 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78413 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78412 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78411 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78410 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78409 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78408 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78407 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78406 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78405 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78404 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78402 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78401 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78400 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
78397 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Yet Apache clearly has the worker module installed, not the prefork module:

```
root@garrison:/HostRAID/netboot/IntelNetboot.nbi# /usr/sbin/apache2 -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  worker.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

What gives? Why do I have so many `apache2` processes? This server is under *no* load. (That is, no http requests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but your `ps` output reminded me much of Linux 2.4 - threads used to appear as processes on `ps` until the move from [Linux Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads) to the [Native Posix Threads Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library).

This quote from [this thread](http://lists.debian.org/debian-bsd/2009/09/msg00083.html) seems to confirm my suspicion:

> Under GNU/kFreeBSD threads are process
>   clones, similarly as under linux 2.4
>   series

If this is the case these wouldn't mean worker is malfunctioning. It isn't forking - those are threads you're seeing. Apache docs on `ThreadsPerChild`:

> This directive sets the number of
>   threads created by each child process.
>   The child creates these threads at
>   startup and never creates more. (...)
>   The default value for ThreadsPerChild
>   is 64 when used with mpm_winnt and 25
>   when used with the others.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#threadsperchild

Comment: This is the BSD kernel so that's probably exactly it. Thank you!!