# why are there many httpd process on the machine while i only started one apache httpd service?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd

on a linux machine with apache installed, i did a search for httpd by 
ps -ef | grep httpd,

i saw about 10 httpd processes, why is that?

```
myuser  14732     1  0 Jan12 ?        00:00:10 /home/myuser/webserver/bin/httpd -k start
myuser  14736 14732  0 Jan12 ?        00:00:00 /home/myuser/webserver/bin/httpd -k start
myuser  31309 14732  0 Jan14 ?        00:00:00 /home/myuser/webserver/bin/httpd -k start
myuser  31313 14732  0 Jan14 ?        00:00:00 /home/myuser/webserver/bin/httpd -k start
```

thx.

Comment: Sounds similar to this thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/272296/why-do-i-have-so-many-apache2-processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You started the parent, and the parent started the worker children.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up [Apaches Documentation on MPM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html). This is the definitive guide. I'd also recommend reading up on how Unix Daemons work in general.

Long story (naive) and short:

- You have a "controlling" process
- Each "worker" process handles a client

Comment: thx for helpful comments

Answer (score 1):

These are child processes, the number of which is controlled by the [startservers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers) directive to the apache [prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html) or [worker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html) modules.